# WPF Datagrid IsReadOnly Bind to Property of the current row Item

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid

I need some rows of my DataGrid editable and others not.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items.View}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Timestamp}" Width="Auto" >
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{lex:Loc DateTime}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value}" Width="Auto" >
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{lex:Loc Value}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
```

I got a Property IsEditable in my Items.
and i like to have something like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="{Binding IsEditable, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}}" Binding="{Binding Value}" Width="Auto" >
```

In the meanwhile I do know that this is not possible that easy. Though i can't find a solution which fits to my problem.

**UPDATE**

not that important, though for better understanding i'll add more data from the viewmodel.

```
private ObservableCollection<MeasuredValue> _last60values;
public ObservableCollection<MeasuredValue> Last60Values
{
    get { return _last60values; }
    set { _last60values = value; }
}

Items = new CollectionViewSource();
Items.Source = Last60Values;
```

and my 'MeasuredValue'

```
    namespace PQS.Model
    {
        public class MeasuredValue : CloneableBaseEntity<MeasuredValue>
        {

        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

        .
        .
        .

        private double _value;
        [Range(0.0, double.MaxValue)]
        public double Value
        {
            get { return _value; }
            set
            {
                _value = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Value");
            }
        }

        private bool _isEditable;
        public bool IsEditable
        {
            get { return _isEditable; }
            set 
            {
                _isEditable = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsEditable);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried compiling it? You should also set your `Binding-Mode` to `Two-Way` so the `IsReadOnly` property will change if your model `IsEditable` property changes (as long as you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`)

Comment: Can't you set up an `EditTemplate` for the columns you want editable. That's how it works in Silverlight.

Comment: @ChrisF: I dont want to make specific columns editable. i want to make specific rows editable. e.g. i want to make two of my four cells in my row x editable... one row is equal to one item and i've the Property IsEditable in the Item.

Comment: @Bob: yeah ive tried. get an error2.. IsEditable is not a property of my viewmodel its a Property of my Items i display in my DataGrid

Comment: @Hown_ - ah my misunderstanding. Sorry.